# How to put an input in each row of my table automatically?

Tags: reactjs

how to put an input in each box of my tables automatically without typing each time the name of colum ?
I use  from core UI library

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please copy the relevant code into your question instead of linking to a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [map](http://www.hackingwithreact.com/read/1/13/rendering-an-array-of-data-with-map-and-jsx), for example:

```js
const columnNames = ["inferieur a 30", "de 30 a 40", "superior a 40"];

<CDataTable
  //...
  scopedSlots={columnNames.map(columnName => {
    return(item => {
      <td>
        <CInput
          type="texte"
          key={columnName} // you hav to add a key when generating components from an array
          id={columnName}
          name={columnName}
          defaultValue={item[columnName]}
          onBlur={(event) => this.handleChange(columnName, event, item)} // note having to change this
        />
      </td>
    })
  })}
>
```

Comment: an error : Line 81:11:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: i think erreur in return()

Comment: Now i Don't have error but i have table without input

Answer (score 0):

thank you Hussein Duvigneau for your help
its avec reduce() not map because its object key function not array

return(
<CDataTable items={tableData} scopedSlots={columnNames.reduce((acc,col)=> {
acc[col] =  (item,index) => (



)